# moment.tz.guess not displaying the correct value

Tags: javascript, html

I need to save the timezone in a Webflow app and I've written the following simple HTML:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var m = moment.tz.guess();
//var s = m.format();

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = m;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's displaying 'undefined' in the browser and I'm getting this weird error message in the console:

'Moment Timezone found Europe/London from the Intl api, but did not have that data loaded.'

That is the correct timezone, so is there a way of getting it to print my correct timezone please, not just undefined.  I'm using Chrome 89.0.4389.82.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(moment.tz);
var m = moment.tz.guess(true);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = m;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works.